# close() in generator expression

Tags: python, generator

Is `close` ever used when using a generator/generator expression, or is it mainly an internal method? For example:

```
def odd_less_than_six():
    n = 1
    while n < 6:
        yield n
        n += 2

... 
>>> f=odd_less_than_six()
>>> next(f)
1
>>> next(f)
3
>>> next(f)
5
>>> next(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Or manually:

```
>>> f=odd_less_than_six()
>>> next(f)
1
>>> f.close()
>>> next(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Is there ever a real-world use case for when `close` would be called manually in a generator method?

Comment: `file` objects are iterators, it's normally to call `close()` on them.

Comment: There can also be cases where e.g. some other part of the code still has a reference to the iterator, but you want to make sure it raises `StopIteration` in case that part of the code tries to iterate it.